# Is the return statement returning an anonymous object?

Tags: javascript

```js
 var dom = function(params, context) {
    return new GetOrMakeDom(params, context);
  };
```

Is the return statement in the code returning an anonymous object? If so, the "this" object is the only object that has a reference it to? If not, who else has a reference to it?

```js
function OuterFunction()
{
    return new newFunction();
};

function newFunction()
{
     if(this === undefined)
     {
       console.log("this is equal to the global window object");
     }else
     {
       console.log("this is not equal to the global window object");
     }
};

OuterFunction();
```

Comment: `console.log(OuterFunction());`

Comment: What is an "anonymous object" and what would be a "non-anonymous object"? Note that `this` is not "an object that has a reference to" but when only executing this snippet and looking at `this` inside `newFunction`, it will be the same as what `OuterFunction` returns at the end. Also note that you posted a similar question to this some hours ago, got closed, deleted it, changed the wording somewhat and now we get this.

Comment: anonymous object is {a: 1, b: 2}, anonymous object is var newObject = {a: 1, b:2}

Comment: Why not check to see what it returns? I smell homework...

Comment: I added new code at the top to show what I'm trying to understand..

Comment: I would recommend reviewing [MDN's documentation for `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) to understand what it is really doing.  I'd guess if you were to look at the function body of `GetOrMakeDom`, it would be setting certain properties and functions on itself, and then the whenever `dom` was called in the code it would be further leveraging those properties and functions.  That `new` operator alters how the function is invoked-- see [Object Oriented JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having some confusion here.  You are getting bizarre results because you are using the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator strangely.  Generally it is used on a constructor function-- however, your function doesn't really define any properties for itself as a constructor generally would, so when it returns an instance of your `newFunction` "constructor", the instance is simply an empty object.

```js
function OuterFunction() {
    return new newFunction();
};

function newFunction() {
    if (this === window) {
        console.log("this is equal to the global window object");
    } else {
        console.log("this is not equal to the global window object");
    }
};

const test = OuterFunction();
console.log(test);
```

It is the `new` operator that causes the function to be invoked as a constructor and `this` to be bound to the newly created instance.  If you were to omit the `new` operator:

```js
function OuterFunction() {
    return newFunction();
};

function newFunction() {
    if (this === window) {
        console.log("this is equal to the global window object");
    } else {
        console.log("this is not equal to the global window object");
    }
};

const test = OuterFunction();
console.log(test);
```

You see that `this` refers to `window` in this instance and `undefined` is the return.

Also, I believe you have some incorrect terminology-- "anonymous object" is really not a term I have heard.  You may be confusing this with "anonymous function", which is an function declared without a name.

Comment: Are you saying if(this === newFunction) // true?

Comment: I know the "this" keyword is always an object but the logic is not making sense. this === window // false, this === newFunction // false, this === OuterFunction // false...

Comment: No, that's now quite right.  Because you invoke `newFunction`, `this` is bound to a new instance object of the ostensible "constructor" function, and returned from that function.  So `this` will equal the new instance of the object.  If you were to do `window.myInstance = this` at the end of `newFunction` and then check `test === window.myInstance` at the end it would evaluate `true`.  I think the important, salient question to really understanding your issue is: why are you invoking `newFunction` with the `new` operator?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to understand a particular code in the dom.js file, these particular lines     var dom = function(params, context) {
    return new GetOrMakeDom(params, context);
  };